# Need to resize and replace millions of images on Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I currently use Django for my backend and iOS for my front end. Users can take pictures from the iOS app and upload them to Amazon S3. The app provides Django with the url to the images so that the user can retrieve them later.

It's a very simple setup. However we recently ran into a problem. The images need to be re-sized so that download speeds for the user are faster. Django is backed by a postgresql database which stores all the images links.

This creates another problem since the database already contains url links to the old images so I need to find a way to batch download all the images within a certain bucket, re-size them and then re-upload them to S3 to replace the old image in such a way that it has the same image name as the old image did.

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure all of your customers want this?  Personally, I would be pretty mad if I discovered that all of the images I was storing with your service had their quality reduced.

Comment: @F.J we thought about those concerns, but the quality is just way too high for the mobile devices. It creates longer than normal retrieval times for customers who are on a 3G or LTE connection.

Comment: @F.J Seconded. My advice would be to instead detect a mobile connection and serve a downsized version of the image in that circumstance, instead of doing a lossy transform on the original version of everything. Caching the downsized versions should help a lot with load concerns, and this way you won't risk inducing justifiable fury in your customers.

Comment: @AaronMiller I like your suggestion. You should run through and decrease the size/quality of picture, but also keep the original, if the user wants faster connection, they can select it and access the lower quality image.

Comment: @enginefree I'd actually recommend instead defaulting to low quality on a slow/high-latency connection, with an option to view at full quality for those who don't mind taking the hit on load time. Of course, that assumes it is feasible to detect a lousy connection.

Comment: I thought that's what different sizes are for, when it comes to "responsive" needs. You should really just be keeping the original, and generate original-NxN, original-MxM etc and for the resized ones do whatever optimization you want to, so long they're within your terms, agreements with users.

Comment: @woozyking even that's an option I'm willing to consider. If you have the solution, please posted it below so that I may upvote your answer

Comment: @AaronMiller Thats what I meant, sorry. By size i meant the size of the file, not the size of image.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just say we use an image library, such as [`Pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0)

Sample usage:

```
from PIL.Image import Image, ANTIALIAS

img = Image.open('your_image_filename')
ogn_size = img.size  # gives you a tuple (x, y)

# base on ogn_size do proportional resizing, let's say by 50%. also apply the recommended
# downsizing high quality filter ANTIALIAS
image_half = img.resize( int(ogn_size[0] * 0.5), int(ogn_size[1] * 0.5), ANTIALIAS )

# more stuff to do, such as optimization on save
image_half.save( "your_image_filename_half", optimize=True,quality=80 )
```

Please read the documentation for more options and APIs you may be able to utilize in your production code base https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/